# Windows Server 2008 web pages timing out unless I RDP into it first

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, windows-server-2003, iis

Right now we have Comcast as our ISP and I'm using their router to forward the public IPs through to three servers. The servers have one NIC each and a private and public IP address attached to each NIC.

The problem I'm having is whenever there is no activity for over a minute, all of a sudden I cant get to my web page.

I have a landing page website and a new SharePoint site each running on a  Windows Server 2008 R2 VM and an old SharePoint site running on a Windows Server 2003 R2 VM. I never have any problems with the server running Windows Server 2003. It never seems to go to sleep like the other two. All three servers are now virtualized. Up until three days ago just the Windows Server 2003 and one of the Windows Server 2008 servers were.

If I want the webpage to come up all I have to do is initiate a remote desktop session and all of a sudden it "wakes up" and I can now access the web page. I dont even have to log in via RDP just initiate a connection.

Comcast is telling me everything looks good on their end so they are not helping. The funny thing is I can RDP into the SharePoint server, then RDP into the other Windows Server 2008 server and work on it, yet I still cant access the web page on the 2008 server.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like some sort of sleep functionality on the VM or the network.  Do you have a VPN between your computer and the VMs?  If so, that could be a good candidate for a session that is only established through one protocol (RDP).

To troubleshoot try pinging the server and see if that makes a difference or leads to any clues on where it's sleeping.  Also check event viewer for any clues on network or hardware sleeping.  Check your network setting to make sure that there aren't any odd settings there.

If you RDP to the new SharePoint server from another server and remain connected, then does the session work from your local computer?  This will tell you if the sleep is related to the new SharePoint server as a whole, or if it's network related for each connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is No VPN between my computer and the VM's just using RDP.

Ping doesn't wake the computer up when i cannot get to the website.

I can remote desktop in to that server, or another server and they will still time out. I just tested something else, instead of using the static IP's that comcast gave me, i used their gateway address and forwarded the ports to my server. Now it never goes to sleep, so i feel like its something wrong on comcast's end. The problem is the web server is up all the time now but the sharepoint site is not.